# R Prediction on a Linear Regression Model

Tags: r, linear-regression, prediction

I'm sure this is something that can be done, just not sure how!
I have a dataset that is around 500 rows(csv) and it shows footballers match stas(e,g passes, shots on target)etc.I have some of their salaries(around 10) and I'n trying to predict their salaries using a linear regression equation.

In the below, if Y is salaries, is there a way on R to essentially autopopulate? what the rest of the salaries might be based on the ten salaries I do have?

```
lm(y ~ x1 + x2 +x3)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is what the [`predict`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/class/html/knn.cv.html) function does.

Note that you don't need to call `predict.lm` explicitly. Because the result of a call to `lm` is an object with class `"lm"`, R "knows" to use `predict.lm` when you call `predict` on it.

Eg:

```
lm1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 +x3)
y.fitted <- predict(lm1)
```

Comment: great,thanks a million!I  If I have actual total salaries per team and can get a total predicted salary per team, is there an appropriate statistical test I can do to determine if there is a statistical difference between predicted and actual? I was thinking Chi-Squared but not sure if this makes sense

Comment: @CarolineCoughlin you will have to chop up salary into "bins" and that makes your measure of goodness of fit entirely dependent on how big to make the bins. The standard way to measure goodness of fit in linear regression is R squared and adjusted R squared, but there's no corresponding test for goodness of fit. You can run a t test on it because it's a squared correlation, but even if you reject the null of "zero r squared" it doesn't mean that your predictions are good.

Comment: In general fitted and actual will always be "different" because a fitted value is a conditional _average_. That is, generate prediction Y1 with inputs X1 and Z1. Y1 is not really the "prediction" for a single guy with X1 and Z1; but if you observe a large number of guys with exactly X1 and Z1, on average they will also have Y1. The squared difference an estimated Y and the true Y depends on the amount of variance (aka "random variation") in Y that the model does not capture. R squared can be interpreted as the "fraction of variance explained" by the model

Comment: Head over to stats.stackexchange.com if you have more questions

Comment: Hi Thanks for this, on Linear Regression fit question, I got the code to work lm(y ~ x1 + x2 +x3) but it only predicts a value for the ten variables I know, is there a value I need to input for the unknowns to get a predicted value back?. Also is there a way to get these results into a new csv file?

Comment: @CarolineCoughlin for help on the `predict` function type `?predict` or `help("predict")` in the console. To save the results you will want to look at the `write.table` and `write.csv` functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to test the predictive accuracy of your model using cross validation with the function `cv.lm` in the DAAG library. With this function you create test data to test the model which is generated using training data.